# How do i invoke a batch script remotely in a windows 2000 terminal using commands from windows 7

Tags: batch-file, windows-task-scheduler, windows-2000

I have a Batch file in legacy Windows 2000 server from a windows 7 environment.

Using schtasks to create a task and run the same through it gives me result ERROR : THE REQUEST IS NOT SUPPORTED. Is there a different approach to invoke the script remotely.

PS: I cannot install any 3rd party software to work around it.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `wmic`

```
wmic /node:SERVERNAME1 "cmd /c somebatch.cmd"
```

For more information simply open `cmd.exe` and type `wmic /?`

**EDIT:** I actually just realised you are using Windows 2000 and you would probably need to enable wmi on the server, see this [link](https://www.poweradmin.com/help/faqs/how-to-enable-wmi-for-remote-access/)

Comment: Hi Gerhard, Looks like this didnt help either.

Comment: @VigneshVikiDj How? Can you be specific?